# Make My App Able To Open Web Links (So it can be set as default by user)

Tags: android, default

I have made a web browser app, but I am unsure of how I would make it able to open links. For example, if the user receives an email with a link in it, they get the option to open the link in my app, and set the app as default if they want to. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register intent filter scheme "http"

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html

Here is an example

http://androidsmith.com/2011/07/launching-an-android-application-from-a-url/

Comment: That's not really what I meant; I want to be able to click a link, say 'www.google.com', that has been emailed to me or something, and I want my app to be able to be selected in the 'Choose an app' dialog (so, on my Nexus 7, I can choose Chrome or my browser), and it would pass a String to my browser or something and the link would open in my WebView.

Comment: That is exactly what the example does. Every time you click on a link. That essentially is a VIEW intent and any app with matching filter can handle it. If there is more than one matching app, then user get to choose.

Comment: 3 years on, I've accepted this - I know enough about Android now to understand your link! (The second link is broken though)